# Pass System/Environment Information to log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, environment

It is possible to pass the system/environment information to the log4net log in my C# WinForms application?

It would be good to have details like what Windows version they are using, if any Service Packs are installed, what .Net they have installed etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Log4Net for a long time, but can't you set this information to the global or thread context?

> log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["WindowsVersion"] = windowsVersion;

Then you can output this information in your log file with the following pattern:

> %property{WindowsVersion}

See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html for more information.

Comment: Is is possible to add this information to the top of the log file, for every log file created?